# Как добавить столбик года и счетчик недели в pandas и еще добавить переименование столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

Подробности вставила ниже на гугл щитс.

Дата в исходнике у меня генерируется из csv таким образом:

```
csv_file["столбик_в_csv_со_временем"].dt.floor("D")]
```

У меня есть df такого вида: (исходник)

```
Дата          |Показатель_1|Показатель_2|
______________|____________|____________|
YYYY-MM-DD    |2           |3
_____________ |____________|____________|
YYYY-MM-DD    |1           |1
______________|____________|_____________
YYYY-MM-DD    |1           |4
______________|____________|_____________
YYYY-MM-DD    |2           |3
______________|____________|_____________
YYYY-MM-DD    |0           |0
```

Мне нужно сделать сумму показателей в 1 неделе с понедельника по воскресенье. Сделать счетчик недель и вынести год в отдельный столбик.

(Результат)

```
Год           |Неделя      |Показатель_1|Показатель_2|
______________|____________|____________|____________|
2020          |1           |3            5
_____________ |____________|____________|____________|
2020          |2           |1            6
______________|____________|____________|____________
2020          |3           |4            10
______________|____________|____________|____________
2020          |4           |3            11
______________|____________|____________|____________
2020          |5           |0            12
```

Как это реализовать? У меня следующие проблемы с реализацией: я не знаю, как выделить год из даты и не знаю, как сделать сумму недели, так как я не знаю, как по дню сделать так, чтобы определялся день недели и счетчик недель не знаю как сделать.
[ссылка на данные](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yea2DyTz9ChD1nS2y1gYwojfOBiJx55JEq7476dtG5g/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: пример исходных данных приведите. чтобы было, на чем вам показать.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду прям файлы? они оооочень большие 30k+ строк. или можно самой сделать?

Comment: ну не целиком файлы. часть хотя бы. Если, конечно, вас устраивают теоретические решения без возможности проверки, то оставьте все как есть.

Comment: а как лучше прикрепить просто текстом?

Comment: можно текстом, можно ссылкой на гуглдокс или, на худой конец, на файлообменник.

Comment: @strawdog здравствуйте! простите за поздний ответ. я добавила данные. вы сможете еще посмотреть?

Comment: @MRO Мой ответ вам не помог, ничего не получилось?

Comment: А по ссылке пишет "Нет доступа"

Comment: Здравствуйте! а сейчас получилось? до получения вашего ответа, я забыла упомянуть, что там есть еще 2 категории (описала их в примере в ссылке). Из-за этого реализация задуманного для меня стала сложнее

Comment: @MRO Вообще тут не принято существенно менять вопрос по ходу дела, потому что все комментарии и ответы тогда сразу становятся неактуальными. Если вы можете расширить ваш вопрос - это одно, если вопрос уже в чём-то другом - надо задавать новый вопрос. Я посмотрел ваш файл - вы же сами пока не знаете, что вам нужно считать, как тут можно ответить? Вы должны сначала добиться чёткой постановки от того, кто вам дал задачу.

Comment: поняла вас, нет, я понимаю, что мне нужно считать, но не знаю, как сделать группировку в sheets. для меня данное изменение показалось дополнением, а не изменением. Могу создать новый вопрос сразу со всеми дополнениями, но он будет повторять данный. Нужно ли это делать?

Comment: @MRO Ну, в принципе, можно и так и так, только если будете менять этот вопрос, не выпиливайте из него изначальные вопросы, а сделайте к ним дополнение. Просто вам придётся менять тут почти всё, включая заголовок, картинки и описание. Мне кажется, лучше тогда новый вопрос задать - с новыми картинками и т.д., но делайте как вам удобнее.

Comment: @MRO Про год и неделю то я вам ответил, можете новый вопрос про остальное уже задать. И я пока не очень понимаю, что же вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну по идее как-то так:

- Год: берёте из даты `.dt.isocalendar().year`
- Неделя года: берёте из даты `.dt.isocalendar().week`
- Группировка по году и неделе и суммирование: `.groupby(["Год","Неделя"]).sum()`

Если дата у вас не в колонке, а в индексе, то синтаксис там может быть другой, не через `.dt`.

Если `Pandas` старой версии, то там нет `.isocalendar()` и будет что-то вроде `.dt.weekofyear`.

Добавил работающий код для ваших данных. Дальше у вас непонятно, что нужно считать.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Stackoverflow данные - Входные данные.csv', parse_dates=['Date1'], dayfirst=True)
df['Год'] = df.Date1.dt.isocalendar().year
df['Неделя'] = df.Date1.dt.isocalendar().week
df[['Date1','Год','Неделя']]

         Date1  Год Неделя
0   2020-08-24  2020    35
1   2020-08-25  2020    35
...
20  2020-09-13  2020    37
21  2020-09-14  2020    38
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я сейчас буду тестировать.

Comment: мне пишет сейчас cmd AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date1'

Comment: @MRO Я просто сохранил ваш файл в формат CSV, больше ничего не делал

Comment: окей, а вы не знаете , ход работы такой же если вместо csv файла другой датафрейм, который я преобразовываю

Comment: @MRO Так надо смотреть какие у вас там поля вообще есть. Если дата у вас в другом поле, так и будет другое название поля, не `Date1`, а ваше